# Capturing text change events in a QComboBox

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qcombobox, qkeyevent

I am developing a Qt application on Red Hat Linux. I want to capture Carriage Return key press events in a `QComboBox`.

I have connected a slot to the signal `editTextChanged()` which is emitted for every key press but not for the *Enter Key*.
Why so? Is there any other way to detect *Carriage Returns*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you wrote a slot and connected it to `QComboBox::editTextChanged()` signal.
This signal is fired when the text changes and *Enter* does not change the text, it accepts it. If you want to capture *Carriage Return*, there are a number of ways you can follow.

1. Subclass `QComboBox`.
   Override `keyPressEvent()` : first call `QComboBox::keyPressEvent()` and then check if the pressed key is *Enter*. If it is, emit a signal.
   Use this subclass whenever you need. Search about promoting widgets in QDesigner if you don't know how.
2. Implement a new class which inherits `QObject`. In this class, override `eventFilter()` : check if the event is a key press. If it is, check if it is the *Enter* key. If it is, emit a signal.
   Then, create an instance of this class and set it as event filter to your `QComboBox`. Connect a slot to this instance's signal, which you implemented.

If these are not clear, i recommend reading the following pages:

[Using Custom Widgets with Qt designer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

[Qt Events & Event Filters](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/eventsandfilters.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could also look into the `activated( const QString& )` signal.  It might be emitted when the user hits enter.

Comment: this is just what I needed.  Frustratingly editTextChanged() gets called before the other signals when the user changes selection, so there's no way to know /why/ the text has changed.  If I got an activated() or a currentIndexChanged() signal before editTextChanged() then I could do something different...  Alas.